# Peer to Peer Call using Twilio

Tags: android, kotlin, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I have a voice call requirement that include two apps, Technician app and Customer app. I don't want to include phone numbers in this process. I want to call from technician app to customer app and vice versa. I looked through Programmable Voice SDK but it seems in works via phone numbers. Is it possible without using phone numbers or what API should I use.?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio can call a number of endpoints including phone numbers (PSTN), SIP, and Twilio Client (Javascript, iOS, and Android). Your question includes an Android tag. If Android is the platform of interest, try using the [Twilio Voice Android SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/android):

> Twilio Programmable Voice SDK for Android allows you to add
> voice-over-IP (VoIP) calling into your native Android applications.